# Get Chrome pageAction icon to appear for an URL list in JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am currently developing a Chrome Extension and I want that the pageAction icon appears for an amount of URL's (around 500).

In my **background.js** file (among other code), I have this:

```
// Called when the url of a tab changes
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    // If the tabs url starts with "http://specific_domain"
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http://specific_domain') == 0) {
    // Shows the page action
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
};

// Listen for any changes to the URL of any tab
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

I can get it to work on a specific site already, but I want to change the 'http://specific_domain' to a list of permitted sites, like a white list. I have access to a JSON file that is online.

Here's a snippet of it:

```
{
  "antelife.com": {
    "fbid": "AntElifecom",
    "type": "store",
    "name": "AntElife"
  },
  "amazon.com": {
    "fbid": "Amazon",
    "type": "store",
    "name": "Amazon"
  }, 
  "ebay.com": {
    "fbid": "eBay",
    "type": "store",
    "name": "eBay"
  },
  "mobilegeeks.com": {
    "fbid": "mobilegeekscom",
    "type": "publisher",
    "name": "Mobile Geeks"
  }
}
```

I want to extract the domains, and somehow iterate for all of them and if they are on the list, the pageAction icon should appear. Something like this:

```
function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  for (var i = 0, iLength = whiteListUrl.length; i < iLength; i++) {
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http://www.'+whiteListUrl[i]) > -1) {
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
      notification.show();
      break;
    }
  }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(checkForValidUrl);
```

Any kind of help should be useful. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? Which specific part of the problem you don't know how to do? Also, I urge you to take a look at [`declarativeContent` API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent), it may be a much better approach for showing a page action.

Comment: Hi @Xan, thank's for the quick response, I'll take a look at declarativeContent. The part that I'm stuck is with constructing the whiteListUrl from my JSON, and them use it properly in my checkForValidUrl function.

Comment: Are you able to load the JSON from your online source? Add that code to the question so it's easier to work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a json string you can get url's list in this way;

```
var urlObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var whiteListUrl = Object.keys(urlObj);
```